# how to delete one of two duplicates in each column and merge them in r

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data which consists of two columns and some duplicates on these columns. I want to remove duplicates for each column and then gather all unique values keeping column names.

```
 data<-structure(c(10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("d1", "m1"), c("year2036", "year2037", 
"year2038", "year2039")))

   year2036 year2037 year2038 year2039
d1       10       11        5        3
m1       10       11        5        5
```

And the output will be like:

```
year2036 year2037 year2038 year2039 year2039 
      10       11        5        3        5 

out<-structure(c(10, 11, 5, 3, 5), .Names = c("year2036", "year2037", 
"year2038", "year2039", "year2039"))
```

I tried `unique(r[c(1:8)])` but it is just giving unique numbers removing column names.

Comment: Your desired output is not a "good" output. Vectors with duplicate names are technically permitted by R, but are ambigous and should not be used anywhere. Consider out['year2039'] in your example. It only returns `3`. What if you wanted to refer to the 5? So your desired output should not be used!

Comment: Following up on the comment of @Julian_Hn, I would suggest du use pivot_longer to and handle the data in this format.

Comment: @Julian_Hn yeah I agree with you about bad data type but my point was execute functions for each element. The function will be applied to both year2039[5] and year2039[3]. Hence, I could not figure out any other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique` in `apply` and `stack` the result.

```
stack(apply(data, 2, unique))
#  values      ind
#1     10 year2036
#2     11 year2037
#3      5 year2038
#4      3 year2039
#5      5 year2039
```

Or in the format you wanted:

```
x <- stack(apply(data, 2, unique))
setNames(x$values, x$ind)
#year2036 year2037 year2038 year2039 year2039 
#      10       11        5        3        5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    distinct(value)

 # A tibble: 5 x 2
 # Groups:   name [4]
   name     value
   <chr>    <int>
 1 year2036    10
 2 year2037    11
 3 year2038     5
 4 year2039     3
 5 year2039     5
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to have data with same column names. Here is a solution which gives same structure as your expected output but with modified
column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(row = data.table::rowid(name)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, row), values_from = value)

#  year2036_1 year2037_1 year2038_1 year2039_1 year2039_2
#       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1         10         11          5          3          5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
stack(dapply(data, MARGIN = 2, FUN = funique))
  values      ind
1     10 year2036
2     11 year2037
3      5 year2038
4      3 year2039
5      5     <NA>
```